# Trying to delete all shared memory and semaphore arrays in ipcs but get permission denied?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, permissions, ipcs

Can't find this anywhere online but when trying to delete semaphore arrays and shared memory using `ipcrm -m id.`

I get this error `permission denied for id (<id num>)`. Any reason why?

Comment: On what basis do you suppose that you *should* have permission to remove the IPC objects in question?

Comment: All the time. Do I have to edit permissions to edit the ipcs?

Comment: Only administrator users can use ipcs, i.e. root.  Try `sudo ipcrm -m id`

Answer (score 0):

From [the `ipcrm` manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ipcrm.1.html):

> In order to delete such objects, you must be superuser, or the creator or       owner of the object.

If you, acting as an ordinary user, attempt to remove an IPC object for which you are neither creator or owner (usually both the same account) then permission will be denied.  This is what is what you describe.

If you have sudo privileges on the machine then you should be able to engage them to remove others' IPCs.  You should rarely, if ever, need to do this, however, because you can already remove your own IPCs, and it is almost never a good idea to remove anyone else's.  If you have to ask the question, then you are not experienced enough to distinguish whether it is safe or appropriate to remove IPCs that do not belong to you.